# How do I fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'?

Tags: python

I'm trying to remake Tic-Tac-Toe on python. But, it wont work.

I tried
`

```
game_board = ['_'] * 9
print(game_board[0]) + " | " + (game_board[1]) + ' | ' + (game_board[2])
print(game_board[3]) + ' | ' + (game_board[4]) + ' | ' + (game_board[5])
print(game_board[6]) + ' | ' + (game_board[7]) + ' | ' + (game_board[8])
```

`
but it returns

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\tutorial.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(game_board[0]) + " | " + (game_board[1]) + ' | ' + (game_board[2])
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

`

Comment: `print(game_board[0])` will print `game_board[0]` and return None; subsequently, you're appending another 'str'. That's why you're seeing that error

Comment: Please don't edit "solved" into your question. That is what accepting an answer is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the error carefully to find your answer.

```
print(game_board[0]) + " | " + (game_board[1]) + ' | ' + (game_board[2])
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

you have closed the bracket for game_board[0]. An additional **'('** is to be used.

```
print( (game_board[0]) + " | " .....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you put the parenthesis wrongly. It should be

```py
game_board = ['_'] * 9
print(game_board[0] + " | " + (game_board[1]) + ' | ' + (game_board[2]))
print(game_board[3] + ' | ' + (game_board[4]) + ' | ' + (game_board[5]))
print(game_board[6] + ' | ' + (game_board[7]) + ' | ' + (game_board[8]))
```